# Multiple script conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have two items that work separately, but not together. I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to resolve it.

I have a WordPress carousel plugin that is conflicting with the script I have in the footer which is calling jquery.

```
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
```

Obviously, I'm assuming the plugin is also calling for jquery, but if I remove my jquery in the footer, which is being used for the mobile nav, the collapsing nav pulldown stops working.

What is the best way to go about this? I'm not well versed with jquery.

--

**UPDATE:**

I finally got it working.

```
function pm_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script('jquery',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    /* REGISTER ALL JS FOR SITE */
    wp_register_script('topbar',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js');
    wp_register_script('modernizr',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/vendor/modernizr.js');
    wp_register_script('foundation',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/foundation.min.js');

    /* CALL ALL SCRIPTS FOR SITE */
    wp_enqueue_script('topbar');
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');
    wp_enqueue_script('foundation');

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pm_scripts' );
```

Any arguments?

Comment: what is the jQuery version you are using

Comment: She is using `jquery.js?ver=1.10.2`

Comment: jQuery is included in WordPress core, you shouldn't need to include it at all.  Any other script that is dependent on it can be explicitly declared so with the third parameter of wp_enqueue_script which is the correct way to include additional javascript on a WordPress site: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Chrome Console shows "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'supercarousel". Perhaps the supercarousel isn't being registered with jQuery correctly. Try verifying which versions of jQuery are compatible with this plugin.

Comment: @AndrewBartel I had no idea! I'm going to test with that, thanks. On that link you gave, it reads: "You should never hardcode URLs to local scripts". What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using wp_enqueue_script worked!